# ways to add least edge to a graph to make it have oddcycle graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

> An undirected graph is given and first i need to find the least number of edges to make it have odd cycle and second i should find the ways to add these edges

Comment: Hint: You could always add 3 edges to make a triangle.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes but sometime no extra edges is needed :)

Comment: The hint is supposed to get you thinking about how to address those cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Coloring the graph using black and white, that is, starting from arbitrary point using black, painting the adjacent non-painted nodes using white and works on these white nodes similarly.
2. Check if there is an edge have nodes with same color. If yes, there is already an odd cycle.
3. Otherwise, connecting any two nodes with same color makes an odd cycle. That is to say, you need exactly one extra edge and you have C(number_of_black_nodes, 2) + C(number_of_white_nodes, 2) ways to do so.